# MongoDB documents of calulated values for a dashboard vs re-retrieving on each web page view?

Tags: mongodb

If I have a page in a web app that displays some dashboard type statistics about documents in my database (counts, docs created per hour, per day etc), is it best to pre-calculate this data and store it in a separate document (and update as needed), or assuming the collections have appropriate indexes, would it be appropriate to execute queries to retrieve these statistics on every load of the page?

It's not necessary that the data has to be exactly up to date on every page hit/load, so that's why I was thinking to maintain the data I need to display in a separate document that can be retrieved on page hit (or even cached and only re-retrieved every 5 minutes or similar).

Comment: Why not consider a layer of Memcache or Redis especially since you have some tolerance to stale data on the dashboard?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's pretty broad, and I have the feeling you have already identified the key points. Generally speaking, you should consider these questions:

- Do you need to allow users to apply filters? Complex filters usually make pre-aggregation impossible.
- Related: Is it likely that the exact same data is ever queried again? If not, pre-aggregation might need to happen on different levels of granularity (e.g. by creating day / week / month totals and summing these, instead of individual events).
- What is the relation of reads vs. writes on the data? If the number of writes is small, it might be OK to keep counters in real-time, instead of using read-caching.
- What are your performance requirements for cached and uncached queries? Getting fast *cached* queries is trivial, but comes at the cost of stale data. Making uncached queries faster is more tricky and usually requires something like the multi-level approach discussed before - it often doesn't help if old data comes super fast, but new queries take minutes.

Caching works especially well if the data can't be changed later (or is seldomly changed), and the queries remain the same with a certain chance of re-occuring. A nice example are facebook's profiles, where past years are apparently cached for every visitor-profile combination. First accesses are slow, however...

Comment: No customizable filters, the data will be the same for every user viewing the page. There will be many more writes to the underlying documents in terms of number of docs inserted, the dashboard will just give a status/highlevel overview of the data inserted at the current time, but it's not necessary that it has to be absolutely current.

Comment: In that case, caching seems like the way to go. If your data is incremental, different 'levels of detail' can help building the cache, but that might be premature optimization.

Comment: Are cached vs uncached queries a MongoDB feature, or do you mean caching the results retrieved elsewere, like in the web app? This would certainly work - I could hold on to the retrieved counts and only retrieve them once every 5 or 10 mins or something configurable. My main concern was whether I should be concerned if every page hit is executing queries to retrieve the counts to display?

Comment: That depends on lots of factors. I'd store it in the database and always hit the database and only consider storing in the web application if load is too high - after all, it's not a big change...